# os.exec. passing arguments to new file function

Tags: python

I have 2 separate .py files and i want to open a second one from the first and pass arguments to it using os.execlp. Please can you assist on how to pass the arguments.

1st file:

def parent():

```
  a = input("value one:  ")
  b = input("value two:  ")
  os.execlp('python', 'python', 'product.py')
```

2nd file:

def product(a,b):

```
   print("product is", a*b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are separate processes 2nd file should accept command line arguments like this :-

```
def product(a, b):
    print ("product is", a*b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    product( int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]) )
```

Verify that this indeed multiplies two numbers :-

```
python product.py 2 3

product is 6
```

And then invoke it from the first file:-

```
a = input("value one:  ")
b = input("value two:  ")
os.execlp('python', 'python', 'product.py', a, b)
```

Comment: thanks @Himanshu, the first part works. and it does multiply the numbers. only problem is the args list. the error it shows is TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Comment: no worries. thanks its now working. i typecasted a & b to string.